# why reloading with input box checked not applying darkmode function? Its keeping the checkbox checked but no darkmode function activated on reload

Tags: javascript

I have a toggle button(checkbox) thats supposed to toggle darkmode function on check.

but on reload its saving the checkbox status to local storage. But not toggling darkmode function.

for example: if I toggle the box(checked) it turns on darkmode function. but when I reload its keeping the box checked but the darkmode function is not activating. and if I uncheck the box and the recheck it. It then activates the darkmode function. any solution to this?

here is my html

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="save();darkmode(this);" id="dark-switch">
```

here is my js

```
....
....
....
function save() {   
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("dark-switch");
    localStorage.setItem("dark-switch", checkbox.checked);  
}

//for loading
var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dark-switch"));
    document.getElementById("dark-switch").checked = checked;


function darkmode(checkbox) {
    if(checkbox.checked == true){
        body?.classList.toggle("body-dark-mode");
        nav_dark?.classList.toggle("nav-dark-mode");
        doc_dark?.classList.toggle("doc-bar-dark-mode");
        searchterm?.classList.toggle("searchTerm-dark-mode");
        searchbtn?.classList.toggle("searchButton-dark-mode");
        login_menu?.classList.toggle("login-sub-menu-dark-mode");
        .....
        .....

    }
    else{
        body?.classList.remove("body-dark-mode");
        nav_dark?.classList.remove("nav-dark-mode");
        doc_dark?.classList.remove("doc-bar-dark-mode");
        searchterm?.classList.remove("searchTerm-dark-mode");
        searchbtn?.classList.remove("searchButton-dark-mode");
        login_menu?.classList.remove("login-sub-menu-dark-mode");
        ....
        ....
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer and solution I found on reddit and it worked.
Here is the reply from 'senbozakurakageyosi'

Because you are not calling the darkmode function on your page load at all...darkmode function only executes when checkbox is clicked, that's the only place you call it.

add

```
darkmode(document.getElementById("dark-switch"));
```

at the end of the code so it fires when page loads...

also check if your script tag is at the end of your body tag or it is deferred.It will work but I suggest your refactoring your code a bit.